# »die Märze« vs »die März-Monate«

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

Gestern berichtete der ORF in mehreren Ausgaben der [ZIB](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeit_im_Bild#Derzeitige_Ausgaben) vom Temperaturrekord des heurigen März. In verschiedenen Variationen wurde dabei diese Schlagzeile verlesen:

> Was die Temperatur betrifft, ist der März einer der wärmsten **März-Monate** seit Beginn der Aufzeichnungen. Überhaupt sind derartig warme **März-Monate** in den letzten Jahrzehnten immer öfter vorgekommen.

(Eine Woche lang kann man sich das auch noch in der [ORF TV-Thek](https://web.archive.org/web/20170403082645/http://tvthek.orf.at:80/profile/ZIB-1/1203/ZIB-1/13923003/Rekordtemperaturen-und-wenig-Niederschlag/14018308) ansehen, und dort auch die beiden zitierten Sätze nachlesen.)

Die Meldung verlangt ganz eindeutig nach der Verwendung des Plurals von »*März*«, der sowohl laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maerz) als auch laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%A4rz) existiert, und

> die Märze

lautet. (Auch die Rechtschreibprüfung meines Computers hat gegen mehrere *Märze* keine Einwände.) Der Duden bezeichnet den Plural zwar als »*selten*«, aber das liegt wohl daran, dass man selten den Bedarf hat von mehreren Märzen zu sprechen. Als Empfehlung, den Plural im Fall des Vorliegen eines Bedarfsfalls durch eine Umschreibung zu ersetzen, würde ich das nicht interpretieren.

Ich frage mich nun, warum die ZIB-Redaktion keinen Gebrauch von diesem Plural macht, obwohl dieses hier definitiv angebracht gewesen wäre. Diese Frage stelle ich hier aber nicht (dazu müsste ich mich natürlich an den ORF wenden).

Ich frage hier stattdessen:

Ist »*die März-Monate*« eine akzeptable Alternative als Ersatz für »*die Märze*«? Ist es vielleicht sogar die bessere Wahl?

Wenn »*die März-Monate*« in Ordnung ist, warum nicht auch

> Ich habe die letzen **Sonntag-Wochentage** in meinem Wochenendhäuschen verbracht.
>   *statt*
>   Ich habe die letzen **Sonntage** in meinem Wochenendhäuschen verbracht.

Oder

> Gestern parkten vier **Skoda-Autos** vor meinem Haus.
>   *statt*
>   Gestern parkten vier **Skodas** vor meinem Haus.

?

---

### Nachtrag

Flexionstabelle für *März* laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/M%C3%A4rz) und [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/m%C3%A4rz:N:M)

1. Nominativ
   *singular:* der März
   *plural:* die Märze
2. Genitiv
   *singular:* des März oder des Märzes (nur Wiktionary, auch: des Märzen)
   *plural:* der Märze
3. Dativ
   *singular:* dem März (nur Wiktionary, auch: dem Märzen)
   *plural:* den Märzen
4. Akkusativ
   *singular:* den März
   *plural:* die Märze

Wenn man die existierenden Pluralformen benutzt, entsteht aus dem oben zitierten Originaltext des ORF dieser Text:

> Was die Temperatur betrifft, ist der März einer der wärmsten **Märze** seit Beginn der Aufzeichnungen. Überhaupt sind derartig warme **Märze** in den letzten Jahrzehnten immer öfter vorgekommen.

- »*der wärmsten Märze*« ist Genitiv Plural.
- »*warme Märze*« ist Nominativ Plural.

---

### Nachtrag 2

Nachdem in keiner der drei bisher angebotenen Antworten meine Frage beantwortet wurde, wiederhole ich die Frage nochmal:

**Ist »die März-Monate« eine akzeptable Alternative als Ersatz für »die Märze«? Ist es vielleicht sogar die bessere Wahl?**

Ich bin nicht an Spekulationen über die Beweggründe einer vom ORF (oder sonst jemandem) getroffenen Auswahl interessiert. Ich habe dieses Beispiel nur erwähnt um zu zeigen, dass jemand den *März-Monaten* den Vorzug gegenüber den *Märzen* gegeben hat. Ich will nicht wissen, aus welchen Motiven jemand die eine oder andere Wahl treffen könnte. Ich möchte lediglich wissen, ob »die März-Monate« akzeptables Deutsch ist, und ob es vielleicht sogar besser als »die Märze« ist.

Comment: Fragst du dich wirklich, warum die Redaktion das nicht gemacht hat?! Wahrscheinlich fanden sie, dass "die Märze" komisch klingt. Nicht bei jeder Sprachverwendung schaut man, auch nicht als Redakteur, im Duden nach. März-Monate ist auf jeden Fall eine korrekte Bildung des Plurals eines zusammenesetzten Substantivs "der März-Monat"

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Wie du richtig bemerkt hast, habe ich *mich* gefragt, nicht *euch*. Um das noch klarer zu machen, habe ich angefügt: »*Diese Frage stelle ich hier aber nicht (dazu müsste ich mich natürlich an den ORF wenden).*« Meine tatsächlichen Fragen stehen unter der Zeile »*Ich frage hier stattdessen:*«

Comment: Ja, das habe ich ja deswegen auch mitbeantwortet. Da die Frage mit "März-Monate" leicht zu beantworten ist, hatte ich irgendwie das Gefühl, dass Du Dich irgendwie bei uns rückversichern willst, dass der ORF einen in Deinen Augen schlechten Stil verwendet. Dieser Eindruck wird durch die ganze Vorgeschichte erweckt, die Du hättest  weglassen können und sollen, wenn es Dir wirklich nur um die Frage geht, ob "März-Monate" korrekt ist. Das wäre deutlich übersichtlicher gewesen. Deswegen habe ich hier -1 gegeben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Die Antwort scheint mir recht einfach zu sein:

1. März-Monate ist eine korrekte Bildung des Plurals eines zusammengesetzten Substantivs "der März-Monat". Stilistisch ist sie wohl darauf zurückzuführen, dass die Pluralbildung bei Monatsnamen selten ist, und daher ungewohnt klingt.
2. Die anderen von Dir angeführten Beispiele

> Sonntag-Wochentage

und

> Skoda-Autos

unterscheiden sich offenkundig in der Häufigkeit der Pluralbildung. Es ist viel häufiger, dass man Sonntage miteinander vergleicht, als Märze. Ebenso bei Skodas. Der Plural *Märze* ist enorm selten, daher scheint der "Umweg" über die Komposition zur Bildung des Plurals bei *März-Monate* stilistisch eher gerechtfertigt als in Deinen anderen Beispielen.

Answer (score 3):

Dadurch dass eine bestimmte Wortform sehr selten verwendet wird, wirkt der Gebrauch mitunter wie eine Belustigung. So bei

> - Wir hatten einen der wärmsten Märze seit Beginn der Aufzeichnungen.
> - Donnerwetter, derartig warme Märze sind selten!
> - Am Ende des Märzen¹ ist es immer am schönsten.

wie auch bei

> Der Verzehr eines Fisches ist mir bis dato immer bekommen.

Beim ORF will man also nicht verlacht werden, vermute ich, und die von @tofro angeführte Bier-Irritation käme bei Nutzung von *»Märzen«* noch hinzu.

Im Übrigen ziehen ungewöhnliche Wortformen die Aufmerksamkeit auf sich, wodurch dem ein oder anderen Zuschauer die Nachricht entgehen mag, was dem ORF nicht recht sein kann.

<sub>¹Hier ist auch *»Märzes«* möglich (neben der Grundform *»März«*, die hier nicht zur Debatte steht)</sub>

**Ist (a) »die März-Monate« eine akzeptable Alternative als Ersatz für (b) »die Märze«? Ist es vielleicht sogar die bessere Wahl?**

(a) ist ein gültiger Ersatz für (b) und akzeptabel, weil es kein falsches Deutsch ist, gut verstanden wird und keine unfreiwillige Komik transportiert. Und im Rahmen einer Nachrichtensendung mag Behelfslösung (a) durchaus die bessere Alternative sein, weil Irritationen und Ablenkungen vermieden werden – der Zuschauer stolpert nicht.

Zugespitzt könnte man sagen:

> Der ORF wählt die Behelfslösung aus Angst vor den schlimmen Folgen des Originals.

---

Bei den gängigen Pluralformen »*Skodas*« und »*Sonntage*« besteht keine Notwendigkeit, sie durch irgendetwas zu ersetzen². Tut man es dennoch, fällt man auf. Gegenüber dem »*März*« verhält es sich hier also gerade umgekehrt.

<sub>²Es sei denn, *»Skoda«* stellt neben Autos auch anderes her und man will die Produktgruppen vergleichen (*»Skoda«*-Autos, *»Skoda«*-Fahrräder)</sub>

Comment: Ich kann leider nur wiederholen, was ich ohnehin schon ausdrücklich in meiner Frage festhielt. Ich frage hier ausdrücklich NICHT nach den Beweggründen für die Wahl von »März-Monate« anstelle von »Märze«. Ich habe sehr klar hervorgehoben, was ich tatsächlich wissen will, nämlich: »*Ist ›die März-Monate‹ eine akzeptable Alternative als Ersatz für ›die Märze‹? Ist es vielleicht sogar die bessere Wahl?*« und »*Wenn ›die März-Monate‹ in Ordnung ist, warum nicht auch die anderen aufgezählten Beispiele?*«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Im Fragetext sagst du: _»Ich frage mich nun, warum die ZIB-Redaktion keinen Gebrauch von diesem Plural macht, obwohl dieses hier definitiv angebracht gewesen wäre.«_ In meiner Antwort bin ich auf diese deine ursprüngliche Frage deshalb eingegangen, weil man auch ohne den ORF auf sie antworten kann. Spekulativ zwar, aber man kann.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das zeigt nur nochmal, dass die Frage schlecht gestellt ist, weil sie einen sehr langen, aber irrelevanten Einleitungstext hat.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Das du dieser Meinung bist, gibt dir aber nicht das Recht, an den Beginn der Frage eine Überschrift zu setzen, in der du die Frage schlecht machst. Was du als *irrelevante* und *verwirrende* Einleitung bezeichnet, ist die Ursache der Frage.

Comment: Es war als konstruktiver Edit gemeint. Offenkundig hat diese weitschweifige Einleitung viele hier verwirrt - was zu Antworten geführt hat, die deine Frage nicht beantworten, wie du selbst angemerkt hast. Um das zu klären, habe ich das so editiert. "Verwirrend" ging auf die Beobachtung zurück, dass es viele verwirrt. "Irrelevant" ging darauf zurück, dass du selbst sagst, dass du diese Frage nicht beantwortet haben wolltest. Sorry, wollte dir nicht zu nahe treten.

Answer (score 0):

Ich gebe zu, *einer der Märzen* würde mir auch schwer über die Lippen gehen (da denke ich sofort an [Bier](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A4rzenbier) und bekomme Durst) und ich hätte mich als Wetterbericht-Macher auch für diesen Ausweg entschieden. Möglicherweise war das genau der Gedankengang (Ausschluss von Missverständnissen). Ich weiß allerdings nicht, wie weit der Begriff *Märzen* für Bier in Österreich verbreitet ist.

Die *März-Monate* dürfte genauso erlaubt sein, wie

> die Ich-Erzählung
>
> die Apollo-Rakete

Solange man den "März" als Eigennamen betrachtet, entspricht dies auch den Regeln des Rechtschreibrats. Ist man nicht dieser Ansicht, müsste man eigentlich

> Märzmonate

schreiben. Da es sich anscheinend um eine Fernsehnachricht handelt, gehe ich davon aus, dass wir die genaue Schreibweise natürlich nicht kennen.

Comment: Wo nimmst du das N am Ende von *Märzen* her? Dieses N gibt es nur im Dativ (Singular als eine von zwei Varianten und Plural) und im Genitiv Singular (wo es in einer von drei möglichen Varianten verwendet wird). Aber »einer *der wärmsten Märze*« ist Genitiv Plural. Und die »*warmen Märze*« ist Nominativ Plural. »*Märzen*« wäre z.B. in »Ich rede jetzt von **den Märzen** des letzten Jahrhunderts« richtig. Die genaue Schreibweise kennen wir übrigens sehr genau. Ich habe den Text nämlich per Copy&Paste von der ORF-Seite hierher kopiert. Märzen-Bier ist auch in Österreich verbreitet.

Answer (score 0):

Was in der Frage als Zitat aus dem ORF notiert ist, klingt arg holprig.

Die eleganteste (am wenigsten auffällige oder ruckelige) Lösung wäre wohl:

> Noch nie war es in einem März so warm wie dieses Jahr.

Oder wenn man Österreicher sein und bleiben will:

> Noch nie war es in einem März so warm wie heuer.

Hier weitere Varianten, die allesamt gut sind:

> Noch nie war ein März so warm wie der heurige.
>
> Der März war noch nie so warm wie dieses Jahr.
>
> Das Wetter im März war noch nie so warm wie heuer.
>
> Dieses Jahr wurden die höchsten Temperaturen je in einem März gemessen.
>
> Die Temperaturen im März dieses Jahr waren die höchsten, die je in diesem Monat gemessen wurden.

Comment: Das ist zwar interessant (daher kein -1), aber leider auch keine Beantwortung meiner Fragen (daher auch kein +1). Meine Fragen sind: »*Ist ›die März-Monate‹ eine akzeptable Alternative als Ersatz für ›die Märze‹? Ist es vielleicht sogar die bessere Wahl?*« und »*Wenn ›die März-Monate‹ in Ordnung ist, warum nicht auch die anderen aufgezählten Beispiele?*«

Comment: "Die Märze" ist für  mein Gefühl falsch (in der Zeitung) oder witzig (in einem verspielten Brief an einen Freund). Die Beispiele in der Ausgangsfrage hinken alle, wenn man sie am Kriterium misst "könnte das so in der Zeitung stehen". Die Lösungen aus meiner Antwort (mit März stets im Singular) würden hingegen diese Prüfung alle passieren. Das heißt nicht, dass nicht anderswo in der Sprachwelt "Märze" auftreten könnten. Auch "Milche" sollen ja schon getrunken worden sein. Aber doch eher im Scherze. Und, ja: "März-Monate" kann man schreiben, aber elegant ist es auch nicht, finde ich.